# Unpack a list with ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I stumbled upon a weird behaviour when I want to unpack a list only if condition is true.

How can I use the unpacking (*) based on a condition?

Example:

```
def foo1(x1, x2):
    print(x1, x2)

def foo2(x):
    print(x)

l = [7,8]
foo1(*l if True else l) # this works
foo2(*l if False else l) # this does not work
foo1(l if not True else *l) # this does not work
```

Comment: use `if not False`

Comment: @sahasrara62 This is just an example, I use a real condition

Comment: What alternative do you want to do if the condition is false?!

Comment: If it's false I dont want to unpack and if it's true I want to unpack

Comment: I have no idea when you would ever need this and it sounds insane. Whether you want to unpack or not depends on the function you call, not on the argument. `foo2` should always be called without unpacking, `foo1` always with unpacking. If both the function and the argument are highly variable and dependent on conditions, your code needs simplification. At most I would accept `foo1(*l) if True else foo2(l)`.

Comment: @deceze insane is your point of view. I'm a user here who asked a question. being nice does not cost money to anyone! My use case is build a forward loop in generic torch model  (which you might be surprised can be useful) and depending on the type of layer I need to unpack or not

Comment: Most use cases I can think of for this are more cleanly handled with a different code structure. For example, if you have an object that might be a single value or a list of values, it's usually cleaner to wrap single values in a list ASAP instead of trying to conditionally unpack-or-not when you need to use the object. Or for your torch use case, if different layers need to be handled differently, it might be cleaner to dispatch to different code based on the layer type. I don't know what your use case looks like, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @user2357112 In general I agree. but this will require to build a new torch model per change where I want to define a configuration file which parse a model that can be used. and for instance If in the config there is Concat then the input should be a list while if it's Conv2d it will be a single tensor. see https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolo.py (in my case it's more complicated than yolo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not parsed as choosing between `*l` on the left and `l` on the right. `l if True else l` is evaluated, and then the result is unpacked, unconditionally.

There's no way to have a function call expression conditionally either unpack or not unpack an argument. *Something's* getting unpacked if you put a `*` there. What you can do is wrap `l` in another list and unpack that:

```
foo(*(l if condition else [l]))
```